# How can I remove an adorner by clicking it?

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner

My adorner is drawn in code using the drawingContext in OnRender. I want the user to be able to click the adorner, or a button on it, to close it. What would I do in the adorner's MouseButtonEventHandler to do this?

I imagine I need to remove it from the adorner layer of the adorned control, but I can't see how I trigger that from the adorner itself.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better solution - allow the user to drag the adorner (a sticky note in this case) out of the way.